# Разместить текст внутри овала

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, адаптивная-верстка

Мне нужно разместить текст внутри блока овальной формы так, чтобы он не выходил за его пределы. Пробовал следующий вариант с использованием shape-outside:

```
.test-block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.test-block__circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
    height: 100%;
}
.test-block__circle_left {
    float: left;
    shape-outside: url("/assets/img/circle-half-left.svg");
}
.test-block__circle_right {
    float: right;
    shape-outside: url("/assets/img/circle-half-right.svg");
}

.test-block__content {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Здесь "circle-half-(left|right).svg" - это просто изображение половины круга. Текст размещается внутри круга, но при разных width и height элемента изображение не растягивается, а находится внутри элемента, как у фона при background-size: contain. Так вот мне, по сути нужно, чтобы изображение в shape-outside растягивалось на все данное ему пространство. Как это реализовать?

Comment: использовать текст внутри svg

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , Мне еще нужно, чтобы была возможность редактирования текста. Т.е. элемент с текстом должен быть либо textarea, либо иметь атрибут contenteditable.

Comment: @Sevastopol' , Работает прекрасно, если ширина и высота элемента равны. А у меня ширина и высота произвольны и не зависят друг от друга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все решил, использовав градиенты:

```
.test-block__circle_left {
    shape-outside: radial-gradient(at right, transparent 75%, black 0);
}
.test-block__circle_right {
    shape-outside: radial-gradient(at right, transparent 75%, black 0);
}
```

В итоге все адаптивно, без картинок и svg.

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить полный код решения, чтобы наглядно было, тогда и плюсы появятся